# How to Get audio file from the project

Tags: iphone

i m not getting sound in iphone here is my code

```
NSString *filepath=[[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"horror (2)" ofType:@"mp3" ];
NSLog(@"filepath=%@",filepath);
url=[[NSURL alloc]initFileURLWithPath:filepath ];
NSLog(@"url==%@",url);
audioplayer=[[AVAudioPlayer alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:url error:nil ];
[self.audioplayer prepareToPlay];
self.audioplayer.currentTime=0;
[self.audioplayer play];
audioplayer.numberOfLoops=-1;
```

Comment: What happens if you replace the error message of `nil` with the address of an `NSError *`, and then print out the details of that error that likely results?

Comment: What do your log statements show?

Answer (score 1):

Check file exists and what error AVAudioPlayer provides :

```
 NSString *filepath=[[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"horror (2)" ofType:@"mp3" ];
if([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:filepath])
{
  url=[[NSURL alloc]initFileURLWithPath:filepath];
  NSLog(@"url==%@",url);
  if(url)
  {
    NSError *error;
    audioplayer=[[AVAudioPlayer alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:url error:&error];
    self.audioplayer.numberOfLoops=-1;
    [self.audioplayer prepareToPlay];

    if (self.audioPlayer == nil)
        NSLog([error description]);             
    else 
        [self.audioplayer play];
  }
  else
  {
    NSLog(@"URL not created");
  }
}
else
{
  NSLog(@"File not exists");
}
```

Comment: i m getting sound only through earphone what is the problem help me

Comment: check iphone not silent or in vibrate mode tick answer if helpful

Answer (score 0):

Examine the error that results from instantiating the `audioplayer` variable:

```
...
NSError *err;
audioplayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:&err];
NSLog(@"ERROR: %@", [err localizedDescription]);
...
```

This will likely give you clues to the root cause of the problem.